# How to detect Escape key if search bar of browser is open?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my website I provide an editor window (simple HTML div with textarea). It can be closed by Escape key.

Javascript:

```
$(document).keyup( function(e)
{
    // ESCAPE KEY closes editor window
    if(e.which == 27)
    {
        // trigger cancel button to hide the editor window
        $('#cancelbtn').click();
        return;
    }
});
```

The problem:

The user might use the browser search bar:

[image: browser search bar]

When the user hits the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key to close the search, it also triggers the javascript code. Consequently the editor window is closed.

How to detect if the search bar of the browser is open? And then not trigger the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key cancel.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use `keydown` instead of `keyup` to prevent the execution because after the searchbar close it automatically set it focus to the last element it has focus on. Also you you can include this in your conditions to make sure that it will only execute if it is focus on the textarea `$('#myTextArea').is(':focus')`.

Comment: That actually worked. I replaced `keydown` with `keyup`. What a simple fix, amazing!  ... Note: It does fix my problem but does not answer the main question of how to detect the active searchbar